# Deployment in JBoss without WAR/EAR

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Can I deploy an application without WAR/EAR in JBoss 6.4.0 eap ?
I need to migrate an application from Weblogic to JBoss. Is it possible to do so without creating the WAR ?

Comment: What type of application are you trying to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your app as an exploded set of files within directories, rather than packaged up within war and ear files. For example, assume you have xxx.ear which contains aaa.war. Under the deploy directory, create a directory named xxx.ear. In that directory create two more directories aaa.war. Into those directories place the contents of the two war files. Also, in the xxx.ear directory place the rest of the contents that would have been in the ear file, such as the META-INF/application.xml file.

Now, for example, you can easily add deploy/xxx.ear/aaa.war/some-new-file.html or edit deploy/xxx.ear/aaa.war/some-file.jsp.